# PyMongo Transform DateField

Tags: mongodb, date, pymongo

I am managing with pymongo to perform some queries over a Premier Leage data base.

https://pkgstore.datahub.io/sports-data/english-premier-league/season-1819_json/data/175e7265560b9ab9102566c5dae7cbf3/season-1819_json.json

However I have some troubles dealing with the `Date` field, which is in `dd/mm/yyyy` string format and I cannot find a way to update my collection by setting another Field in which that Date is transformed into a datetime object, which can be ordered.

```
db = client['PremierLeague']
col = db['2018-2019']
```

I have tried

```
col.update_many({},{"$set":{"DateTime":{datetime.strptime("$Date",'%d/%m/%Y')}}},upsert = True)
```

getting

```
ValueError: time data '$Date' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y'
```

I have also tried

```
col.update_many({},{"$set":{"DateTime":{"$dateFromString":{ "date": "$Date", "format": '%d-%m-%Y'}} }},upsert = False)
```

Getting a `WriteError`

```
WriteError: The dollar ($) prefixed field '$dateFromString' in 'DateTime.$dateFromString' is not valid for storage., full error: {'index': 0, 'code': 52, 'errmsg': "The dollar ($) prefixed field '$dateFromString' in 'DateTime.$dateFromString' is not valid for storage."}
```

Thanks in advance for your interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already solved the problem in python using a for loop, setting a new field for each document in a collection

```
for document in list(col.find()):
    dt = document['Date']
    ident = document['_id'] 
    d_obj = datetime.strptime(dt,'%d/%m/%Y').isoformat()
    col.update_one({"_id": ident}, {"$set":{ "FechaObj": d_obj}})
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct in mongoshell:

```
mongos> db.col.update({} ,[ { $set: { DateTime:{$dateFromString:{dateString:"$Date" ,format:"%d/%m/%Y"}}  }  }],{multi:true} )
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 380, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 379 })
```

and in python:

```
col.update_many({}, {"$set":{"DateTime":{$dateFromString:{dateString:"$Date",format:'%d/%m/%Y' }}}})
```